# docker does not copy crt file

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, docker-compose

I try to build a test application that allow me to use HttpClient to call an action using docker. The application can call the action easily without any problems when using "http://...". When I step forward and start to work with "https://..." I faced several problems that I can not encounter in one question. To be more specific I started to build two Asp.Net Core projects one of them need to call an action from the other project using docker **internal** network using **https**.

My development laptop has:

- Visual Studio 2019 16.9.4
- Ubuntu 20.04 LTS
- Docker Desktop

My docker-compose.override.yml is simply as:

```
services:
  mastercontainer:
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
      - ASPNETCORE_URLS=https://+:443;http://+:80
      #- ASPNETCORE_Kestrel__Certificates__Default__Password=123123
      #- ASPNETCORE_Kestrel__Certificates__Default__Path=/https/test-cert.pfx
    ports:
      - "80"
      - "443"
    volumes:
      - ${APPDATA}/Microsoft/UserSecrets:/root/.microsoft/usersecrets:ro
      - ~/.aspnet/https:/https:ro
      #- ~/.aspnet/https:/https:ro
      #- ./certs:/https:ro
      #- ${APPDATA}/ASP.NET/Https:/https:ro

  detailcontainer:
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
      - ASPNETCORE_URLS=https://+:443;http://+:80
      - ASPNETCORE_Kestrel__Certificates__Default__Password=123123
      - ASPNETCORE_Kestrel__Certificates__Default__Path=/https/test-cert.pfx
    ports:
      - "6001:6001"
    volumes:
      - ${APPDATA}/Microsoft/UserSecrets:/root/.microsoft/usersecrets:ro
      - ~/.aspnet/https:/https:ro
      #- ${USERPROFILE}/.aspnet/https:/https:ro
      #  source: ${USERPROFILE}/.aspnet/https/test-cert.crt
      #  target: /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/test-cert.crt
      #- ~/.aspnet/https:/https:ro
      #- ./certs:/https:ro
      #- ${APPDATA}/ASP.NET/Https:/https:ro
```

Then my docker-compose.yml is like:

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  mastercontainer:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}mastercontainer
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: mastercontainer/Dockerfile
    depends_on:
        - detailcontainer
    
  detailcontainer:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}detailcontainer
    container_name: detailcontainer
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: detailcontainer/Dockerfile
    #ports:
    #    - "443:443"
    #volumes:
    #  - ~/.vsdbg:/remote_debugger:rw
```

and the Dockerfile of the *detailcocntainer* looks like:

```
#See https://aka.ms/containerfastmode to understand how Visual Studio uses this Dockerfile to build your images for faster debugging.

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:5.0-buster-slim AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443
#EXPOSE 6001

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0-buster-slim AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["detailcontainer/detailcontainer.csproj", "detailcontainer/"]
RUN dotnet restore "detailcontainer/detailcontainer.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/detailcontainer"
RUN dotnet build "detailcontainer.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "detailcontainer.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

#WORKDIR "/src/detailcontainer"

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .

# PROBLEM IS HERE
COPY ./test-cert.crt /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/test-cert.crt
# HOW TO COPY

RUN chmod 644 /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/testcert.crt && update-ca-certificates

ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "detailcontainer.dll"]
```

Still I do not know which problems I may encounter while progress in this test solution because the highlighted line in the Dockerfile shown above which is:

```
COPY ./test-cert.crt /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/test-cert.crt
```

does not copy the crt file to ca-certificates folder.

My question is:
**Why Dockerfile does not copy the crt file? and How to copy it?**

Comment: Did you check the permission of file?

Comment: I use Visual Studio docker-compose to run the project. Do you mean USER in docker file? how?

Comment: Is there an error in the output of `docker-compose --build` from your `COPY ./test-cert.crt ...` line?

Comment: @JonasEberle Thank you for your comment. Actually I did not try to run docker-compose outside of visual studio. I used to hit the F5 in visual studio, which does not show me any errors. When I tried your instruction to run the docker-compose build in Ubuntu, finally I got an error as the following:

 => ERROR [final 3/4] COPY ./test-cert.crt /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/test-cert.crt                    0.0s
------
 > [final 3/4] COPY ./test-cert.crt /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/test-cert.crt:
------
failed to compute cache key: "/test-cert.crt" not found: not found

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, I'm new to docker. Due to this [Visual Studio Documentation here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/containers/container-build?view=vs-2019#debugging) It is clear that the `COPY` will not be processed unless it is located in the *base* stage, otherwise, the optimized build of visual studio; which is the default behavior; will ignore any modification to the default DockerFile that Visual Studio assumes to be.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63491671/2670803) gave me a great help to understand more about Visual Studio internal build.

So my Dockerfile should look like the following to get the file being copied:

```
#See https://aka.ms/containerfastmode to understand how Visual Studio uses this Dockerfile to build your images for faster debugging.

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:5.0-buster-slim AS base
#WORKDIR /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/
#COPY ["detailcontainer/test-cert.crt", "detailcontainer/"]
COPY ./test-cert.crt /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/
RUN chmod 644 /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/test-cert.crt && update-ca-certificates

WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443
...
```

The rest of Dockerfile should not be modified.